# Before Shiva-Parvati vivah, the Ganapati who was worshipped as per RCM wasn't Ganesha but 'Karviraksha'. Any scriptural reference?

Tags: shiva, parvati, ganesha

Kindly give any scriptural reference from puranas, agamas, nigama, etc. only.

<sup>RCM = Ramacharitamanasa.</sup>

Comment: Could you please tell, where is this "karviraksha-Ganapati" mentioned? The exact chapter and verse in the RCM ? @Shiva